# Migrating from .net core 1.1 to 2.2 - Regenerate foreign keys

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core-2.2, ef-core-2.2

I have migrate one of my applications from .net core 1.1 to .net core 2.2 and migration was successful and application launching fine. But while I'm trying to generate entity framework migration, it generates a migration for dropping and re-adding foreign keys and indexes of some tables.

```
migrationBuilder.DropForeignKey(
                name: "FK_Commission_Subscription_SubscriptionId",
                table: "Commission");


migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
                name: "FK_Commission_Subscription_SubscriptionId",
                table: "Commission",
                column: "SubscriptionId",
                principalTable: "Subscription",
                principalColumn: "SubscriptionId",
                onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
```

I want to know whether this generation is normal and whether executing this migration script on my database will affect my data in any way...